# 'rpath' does not working in some linux system.

Tags: php, linux

I made a PHP extension for PHP Apache Module. 
I compiled it using gcc-4.9.2.
So I distribute my PHP extension with libstdc++.so.6(libstdc++.so.6.0.10) in same directory. 
And I compiled the extension with 'RPATH=$ORIGIN'.

Most linux system is OK to run.

But, some system(my customer system), extension try to load /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6, and fail to load the extension.

'ldd command' result is fine, it correctly find libstdc++.so.6.0.10(not /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6)

'$LD_LIBRARY_PATH' is empty.

I have had search so many thing using google, but I don't know why, and I don't know how fix it.

Anybody knows, What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

"6.0.10" is rather old.  Perhaps the customer system's libstdc++ has the same `soname` but a later version.

Normally you would make a shared library extension using a *different* `soname` to avoid naming conflicts.

Comment: Hmm, no, customer system's libstdc++ is lower than my libstdc++.so.6. If custumer's libstdc++ is newer than my libstdc++, I think it will be ok to run.

Comment: and, I have question, Can I specify soname of libstdc++? Is it possible?

Comment: You would specify the `soname` using a linker directive (you can see this information  using `objdump -axh`).  But your reply sounds as if you need the library to replace `libstdc++`, which is odd.  I meant that an extension normally would use a *different* library, avoiding the possibility of conflicts.